# How to calculate the probability of the following event?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume there are $k$ identical balls, and $N$ boxes with index $1,2,\ldots,N$.

For the first round, I randomly put the $k$ balls into the $N$ boxes one by one.

Then, in the second round, I repeat the same procedure as the first round.

---

**The question is**: What is the probability of the event that the number of balls in each box is exactly the same as that of first round? Note that in each round, the empty box is allowed.

Any idea is appreciated!

---

### An example

Thanks a lot for the comments of the question. In order to make the question more clear, I make an example. Let $N=2$ and $k=4$.

In this setting, there will be five cases for the first round: $(0,4), (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (4,0)$. We name these five events as $E_0,E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4$. Then for the second round, the required probability is given by
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^4 Pr(E_i) Pr(E_i). 
\end{align}
Now, we talk about how to calculate $Pr(E_i)$,
\begin{align}
Pr(E_i) = \frac{\frac{4!}{i!(4-i)!}}{2^4}.
\end{align}
But, for general case, can we obtain a beautiful solution?

Comment: Check Theorem 2 and the proof via stars and bars [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two).

Comment: @AntoniParellada no.  The outcomes counted by stars and bars are not equally likely to have occurred.

Comment: This seems to me a very difficult problem.  First, it is worth reminding that unless explicitly specified otherwise the random process of "putting balls randomly into boxes" assumes the balls are themselves distinct physical objects, even if they are identical to our eyes, and that if we were to have labeled the balls each of the $N^k$ outcomes if they were labeled would have been equally likely to have occurred.  Our inability to distinguish between some of these outcomes due to the balls being indistinguishable to our eyes does not prevent this from being the case.

Comment: So, the distinguishable outcomes to our eyes happen to consist of collections of outcomes which although in reality distinct are indistinguishable to one another to our eyes.  We have for instance all $k$ of the balls landing in the first box is far less likely than the far more likely outcome of the $k$ balls all landing in the first $k$ different boxes (*where $k\leq N$*)... the probability being different by a factor of $k!$ in fact.  This all being said, I don't see a convenient approach beyond brute force case-work breaking into the different cases counted by stars-and-bars.

Comment: @user2661923: The problem is that stars and bars doesn't give equiprobable results, and if you try to assign a probability to each configuration, I don't know of any method other than implicitly assuming that balls are distinguishable. That is what JMoravitz has also said in his remarks. Anyway, I have deleted my answer, will chew over the matter.

Comment: @user2661923: I have added a rider to my answer and reinstated it.

Comment: @JMoravitz The configurations are nicely conceptualized with stars and bars, although not so the probability distribution, and your pedagogical approach about the split between being indistinguishable to the eye, although physically distinct balls brings the point home.

Comment: @JMoravitz If you have the time, I welcome your independent evaluation of my answer + true blue anil's reaction to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My generic comments may have caused confusion about how I envision using Stars and Bars to attack this problem.  I think that this confusion is best cleared up with an example.

Suppose that there are $(10)$ balls and $(4)$ boxes.  Then, per Stars and Bars, there are $\binom{10 + [4-1]}{[4-1]} = (286)$ solutions that are **not** equiprobable.

I would partition these $(286)$ solutions into groups, where each solution (i.e. distribution of the balls into the boxes) in a specific group **is** equiprobable.

**Group-1** (i.e. G-01)
Distribution of $(10,0,0,0)$, in some order.
Number of elements in group : $(4)$. 
Weight for each element in group: $\binom{10}{10}.$

**G-02**
Distribution of $(9,1,0,0)$, in some order.
Number of elements in group : $(12)$. 
Weight for each element in group: $\binom{10}{9} \times \binom{1}{1}.$

**G-03**
Distribution of $(8,2,0,0)$, in some order.
Number of elements in group : $(12)$. 
Weight for each element in group: $\binom{10}{8} \times \binom{2}{2}.$

**G-04**
Distribution of $(8,1,1,0)$, in some order.
Number of elements in group : $(12)$. 
Weight for each element in group: $\binom{10}{8} \times \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{1}{1}.$

**G-05**
Distribution of $(7,3,0,0)$, in some order.
Number of elements in group : $(12)$. 
Weight for each element in group: $\binom{10}{7} \times \binom{3}{3}.$

$\cdots$

So, the idea is that you would continue identifying groups, counting the number in each group, and adding a weight to each group, until you exhausted all $(286)$ possible distributions.

Now, suppose that you have $r$ groups, $G_1, G_2, \cdots G_r$.

Further suppose that group $G_r$ has $t_r$ elements, with a weight of $w_r$ given to each element in $G_r$.

Then, you will have (for example) that $\sum_{a=1}^r t_a = 286.$

Let $W = \sum_{b=1}^r \left(t_b \times w_b\right).$

Then, each of the weights should be *normalized* by dividing it by $W$.

Now: what are the chances that one of the specific $(286)$ configurations is repeated:

The chance that a specific configuration from G-01 is repeated is $\left(\frac{w_1}{W}\right)^2.$  Since there are $t_1$ such configurations, the chance that the distribution of balls was repeated, where the distribution is represented by some element in group G-01, is

$$t_1 \times \left(\frac{w_1}{W}\right)^2.$$

Therefore, the overall chance that the first distribution of balls into boxes is repeated on the second distribution is

$$\sum_{c=1}^r t_c \times \left(\frac{w_c}{W}\right)^2.$$

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comments of true blue anil, following my answer:

Excerpting from the OP's question:

> What is the probability of the event that the number of balls in each box is exactly
> the same as that of first round?

Further, in the example given by the OP, his computation was

> $\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^4 Pr(E_i) Pr(E_i).$

> Now, we talk about how to calculate $Pr(E_i)$,
> $$ Pr(E_i) = \frac{\frac{4!}{i!(4-i)!}}{2^4}. $$

> But, for general case, can we obtain a beautiful solution?

Also, consider the comment left by the OP following my answer:

> Many thanks for your detailed answer! I think the whole logic is corret. It seems not easy to obtain the number of elements and weight in each group.

Taking your issues one at a time:

[A]

Your interpretation of the OP's question seems to be:

> ...that given a certain outcome of expt 1, what is the Pr that the next expt. gives an identical result.

Based on what I have excerpted, that is **not** the OP's intent.  That is, the OP has demonstrated that, given
a certain distribution occurring in the first placement of $k$ balls into $n$ boxes, the OP knows how to
calculate whether a specific distribution is repeated.  What the OP is *actually* asking is, what are the
chances that the first and second distributions will match, where it is **unknown** what the first distribution is.

We may need to agree to disagree on the intent of the OP's question.

Also, it can be argued that it is actually irrelevant whether the OP's intent is how you interpreted it, rather than how I interpret it.  That is, the OP can routinely use my answer (or your answer), to determine the weight $w_d$ of a distribution.  This means that the OP has demonstrated that he understands that given a certain distribution, the chance of a repeat will be

$$\left(\frac{w_d}{\text{sum of all of the weights}}\right).$$

[B]

I strongly suspect that you are right, that $W = 4^{10}.$  Whether that is true
of not, my formula for $W$ guarantees that the sum of the $(286)$ weights will
equal $W$.  This implies that my formula guarantees that $W$ is appropriate as the
normalizer of the weights.  For the
purposes of this discussion, let's assume that $W = 4^{10}.$

I agree with your math, and your perception of my intent.  Each
of the $4$ distributions in G-01 will be assigned the probability of occurring of
$\frac{45}{4^{10}}.$  I further agree that this implies that the *numerator*
(i.e. the probability) of each distribution occurring will vary from group to
group.  This is exactly my intent.

In reading your [B] objection, it seems that this is actually a repeat of
objection [A].  That is, if you accept my interpretation of what the OP is asking,
then it **is** appropriate that the "*numerators*" (i.e. the weights) vary from
group to group.

Another way of saying the same thing is:

**If** you accept my interpretation of the OP's intent, as debated in [A] above,
then I see no indication that my math is inappropriate.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer! I think the whole logic is corret. It seems not easy to obtain the number of elements and weight in each group.

Comment: @ZHANGWei "It seems not easy to obtain the number of elements and weight in each group."  Agreed, but it is better than [re the example of $(10)$ balls and $(4)$ boxes] examining each of the $(286)$ distributions individually.

Comment: I have 2 issues with your ans: **(A)** The expression is calculating the *Pr of 2 successive expts yielding the same result,* while OP is asking that **given**  a certain outcome of expt 1,  what is the *Pr* that the next expt. gives an identical result. **(B)**  For group $G01$, eg, $t_1$ is $4$, $w_1$ is $\binom{10}8\binom22 = 45$ and $W$, of course is $4^(10)$, so $\frac{w}{W} = \frac{45}{4^(10)}$ To come to the point, by using the multiplier, *a number of different ball placements become the numerator, whereas OP had asked consideration of a specific outcome.*

Comment: The third last line should read "and**W**, of course, is $4^{10}$, so $\frac{w}{W} = \frac{45}{4^{10}}$....

Comment: @trueblueanil See the Addendum that I just added to my answer.

Comment: I agree that **A** is a minor point as one can easily compute in either way. But for $G01$, you are allowing $4000\;0400\;0040\;0004$ in the numerator, whereas if the first experiment showed $4000\;$ OP is asking for the probability of $4000$

Comment: @trueblueanil If you accept my interpretation, then you have to accept that G-01 represents 4 distinct events.  That is, given 10 balls in 4 boxes, I am presuming that having all 10 balls in box-1 is distinct from having all 10 balls in box-2.  This means that (in your parlance) (10),0,0,0, 0,(10),0,0 0,0,(10),0 0,0,0,(10) *should* be treated as 4 separate events.  Alternatively, if your interpretation holds, and if the 1st distribution is (10),0,0,0, then the OP is asking what the chances are of (specifically) (10),0,0,0 occurring in the 2nd distribution. ...see next comment

Comment: @trueblueanil Perhaps I am overlooking something.  If you accept my interpretation of the problem, as debated in the Addendum [A], please be more explicit where you think that my math is inappropriate.  Alternatively, if you accept your interpretation as debated in Addendum [A], then (again) please be more explicit where you think that my math is inappropriate.

Comment: OP is quite explicit (boldface mine): "Then, in the second round, I repeat the same procedure as the first round.

The question is: What is the probability of the event that the **number of balls in each box is exactly the same as that of first round?** Note that in each round, the empty box is allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124559/discussion-between-user2661923-and-true-blue-anil).

Comment: @trueblueanil I have just invited you to a chat.

Comment: Sorry, I had gone out to dinner at that time. On return I posted a message there. This is the first time I have visited the chat room, idk whether messages put there reach you if you are not there at that time. Anyway, OP is not bothered !

Comment: @trueblueanil I left a new response in the chat room.  send me a flagging message, if you think that it will be productive to continue the chat, and i will (again) join the chat.

Comment: idk how to send a flagging message, presumably it has to be here. So tes, we can chat if you wish.

Comment: @trueblueanil I have just joined the chat

Comment: @user2661923: I have  added an addendum to my answer.. Whatever comments you have  can be put against my answer, as here, already too many are there.

Answer (score 1):

Going by @JMoravitz observation "...the random process of "putting balls randomly into boxes" assumes the balls are themselves distinct physical objects, even if they are identical to our eyes..." **I am implicitly assuming that  the balls are distinct in this answer**

Unless specific values are given, we can only give  the answer symbolically

The number of permutations with $k_1$ balls in box $1$, $k_2$ balls in box $2$, and so on with $0\leq k_i,$ and $\sum{k_i}=k$ is

$\dfrac {k!}{(k_1)!(k_2)!...(k_N)!}\;\;= X,$ say, and the probability of getting an identical result on repeating the experiment  will be $\dfrac{X}{N^k}$

---

**ADDENDUM:**

### Can we somehow get a "proper" Pr with balls being unlabeled ?

@user2661923 has made a lot of effort in this direction.

However, leaving aside differences in interpretation as to what OP really wanted, (easily resolvable), my point is that **the complicated process merely makes the balls distinct again**

To explain, I'll use an Yahtzee analogue ($5$ *supposedly* identical balls put in $6$ distinct boxes, so that time in explaining computations is not wasted.
The four entries in each row are
group #/$\;$"Elements"$(t_i)/\;$Weightage$\,(w_i)/\quad(t_i)*(w_i)$
$G01:500000\quad\quad\; \,6\quad\quad 1\quad\quad\; 6$
$G02:410000\quad\quad 30\quad\quad \,5\quad\quad 150$
$G03:320000\quad\quad 30\quad\quad 10\quad\quad 300$
$G04:311000\quad\quad 60\quad\quad 20\quad\quad 1200$
$G05:221000\quad\quad 60\quad\quad 30\quad\quad 1800$
$G06:211100\quad\quad 60\quad\quad 60\quad\quad 3600$
$G07:111110\quad\quad 6\quad\quad 120\quad\quad 720$
........................... $252$.......................$7776$

As can be seen from the totals, $252$ corresponds to a stars and bars orientation, and $7776$ to a die throw one, *so my basic point is that by using* $6^5$ *in the denominator, Pr computations are basically for implicitly distinct balls*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I am still confused about the "reciprocal". For example, we let $k_1=k_2=\ldots=k_{N-1}=0$, and $k_N=k$. Does it mean the probability is one?

Comment: Sorry, have amended !

Comment: I think it is correct now. Thanks for your answer, and this is for the specific case.

Comment: I agree that the comments following my answer are *overloaded*.  It seems to me that you and I have each expressed ourselves clearly, and each of us was understood by the other.  I don't have anything new to say.  For what it's worth, I asked J Moravitz to independently review my answer + your reaction to it.  If he declines, I will try to find someone else; perhaps saul spatz.

Comment: @user2661923: Good idea, maybe they can show a better method.